Does AMP Project support Google One-tap for AMP pages
after Third Party cookie disabled feature, how we intrgrate one tap google Sign in in AMP pages
i tried to embed One tap sign in via amp-iframe methodology, but this code is not working, Can any hemp me to implement one Tap login

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
